# Any text editors that are emacs-like in extensibility but Apple-like in visual aesthetic and design?

Tags: text-editor, emacs

Basically I want a text editor that is:

1. Simple in visual design and uncluttered (like Byword)
2. Powerful and extensible like emacs (with hooks, etc, so I can customize it to my needs). When I say "extensible", I mean the more the better. I don't have a particular hook/extension in mind, but basically the closer to emacs the better. (I think of emacs as being the pinnacle of extensibility.)

I know there's Aquamacs (which meets 2), but Aquamacs looks really ugly and not at all appealing (so doesn't meet 1).

**Please make answers detailed!** Explain why the text editor you are recommending fits this question. In what ways is it extensible? What nice UI touches does it have?
The goal here isn't to build a list of text editors; it's to compile information about exactly how various text editors are both well-designed and extensible.

Comment: I'd say the editor being powerful is much more important than looking good, because more power means it can do more things for you, more things can be automated.

Comment: With Aquamacs/emacs icon bar turned off what is not simple and uncluttered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is actually pretty damn good!

Comment: Please add detail to this answer or it will be deleted. What are some nice UI touches that ST2 has and in what ways is it extensible?

Answer (score 2):

This might be too obvious, but what about setting up a **Terminal** window with a font and color scheme you find attractive (some are suggested, but you can customize to your heart's content)

[image]

and then run… `emacs`.

It clearly meets your second criterion (it, by definition, has all the power of emacs), and as for the first, here's a comparison:

[image]
[image]

They look pretty similar. Choose a different font for the Terminal window if you want a better match. The biggest distinction is that Byword allows fonts that are not monospaced, but emacs insists on monospaced fonts.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favourite is [textmate](http://macromates.com/), there are loads of websites out there that detail how to easily customize it, and it's actually very easy. You can download themes and install snippets for code editing in a variety of different languages and the interface is clean and beautiful.

Answer (score -1):

In the App Store, you can search for "Text Wrangler": it's the free version of BBEdit.

Comment: Please add detail to this answer or it will be deleted. What are some nice UI touches that TW has and in what ways is it extensible?

Answer (score -1):

[Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/) clearly wins on the native UI front. It works a bit like Sublime Text 2 but blends in more beautifully in OS X.

And it has a neat way of adding extras, called Truffles. Most of the extras come directly from github and can be listed and installed with a nice window:

[image: Chocolat Truffles]

You have to see if it's still powerful enough for your needs depending on what exactly you want a text editor to extend with.

Comment: Please add detail to this answer or it will be deleted. What are some nice UI touches that Chocolat has and in what ways is it extensible?